# How to Authenticate to Valence Getting Started Sample?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to use the D2L Valence getting started sample at http://samples.valence.desire2learn.com/samples/GettingStartedSample/. The page gives a username and password to use to authenticate against the test server. But, when I do so, I get a message that the account has been deactivated. Is there a different username and password to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a result of an administrator of the site manually (mistakenly) de-activating the sample user account. You may want to try again after a brief time to see if the problem has been fixed: it appears to have been fixed from what I can see.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I guess I just picked an unlucky time to try it the first time!

Comment: We're sorry you encountered that problem.